# ¿Porque se están cambiando los caráracteres del contenido html de una string al añadirlo a otro elemento con jQuery.html()?

Tags: jquery

Dado el siguiente ejemplo

https://jsfiddle.net/zsmvbt42/10/

Porque al añadir la propiedad

```
style="background-image: url('http://orig00.deviantart.net/296e/f/2008/238/f/0/circle_of_helaing_by_namesjames.jpg');"
```

dentro de un div como una string

```
<div style="background-image: url(xxx);"></div>
```

y luego esto añadirlo al contenido `html` de otro elemento con `.html()` devuelve la ruta como

```
style="background-image: url(" http:="" orig00.deviantart.net="" 296e="" f="" 2008="" 238="" 0="" circle_of_helaing_by_namesjames.jpg");"=""
```

y a la vez añadir la misma ruta como un enlace `<a href""></a>` hacerlo bien

Es decir ¿Porque se están cambiando los caráracteres del contenido `html` de una `string` al añadirlo a otro elemento?

En el mismo ejemplo se vé el metodo 2 que se hace anidando elementos DOM con el efecto deseado

¿Es posible realizar el primer ejemplo sin perder los carácteres de la url?

Comment: Dónde quieres llamar a esa propiedad? En un archivo css o dónde? Por qué no usas el href como dices directamente?

Comment: Si el problema era un fallo tipográfico (como parece que indican en las respuestas), deberías eliminar la pregunta porque no servirá de mucha ayuda a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenías unas comillas de sobra. Te lo actualizo aquí.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zsmvbt42/12/)

```js
var news = $.parseJSON('[{"titulo": "Parche 0.0.0","descripcion": "Pronto estará disponible en la BETA. Incluye correciones de errores y nuevos efectos de hechizo.","imagen":"http://orig00.deviantart.net/296e/f/2008/238/f/0/circle_of_helaing_by_namesjames.jpg","contenido": "El parche incluye numerosas actualizaciones. <ul><li>Corrección de errores</li><li>Nuevas animaciones</li><li>Nueva pantalla de carga</li><li>Nuevo enfrentamiento</li></ul><br>¡No te pierdas todo esto por el módico precio de 5.000 euros!","etiquetas": "Esto, es, el, parche, 0.0.0"},{"titulo": "Parche 0.0.0",  "descripcion": "Pronto estará disponible en la BETA. Incluye correciones de errores y nuevos efectos de hechizo.","imagen": "http://orig00.deviantart.net/296e/f/2008/238/f/0/circle_of_helaing_by_namesjames.jpg","contenido": "El parche incluye numerosas actualizaciones. <ul><li>Corrección de errores</li><li>Nuevas animaciones</li><li>Nueva pantalla de carga</li><li>Nuevo enfrentamiento</li></ul><br>¡No te pierdas todo esto por el módico precio de 5.000 euros!","etiquetas": "Esto, es, el, parche, 0.0.0"},{"titulo": "Parche 0.0.0",        "descripcion": "Pronto estará disponible en la BETA. Incluye correciones de errores y nuevos efectos de hechizo.","imagen": "http://orig00.deviantart.net/296e/f/2008/238/f/0/circle_of_helaing_by_namesjames.jpg","contenido": "El parche incluye numerosas actualizaciones. <ul><li>Corrección de errores</li><li>Nuevas animaciones</li><li>Nueva pantalla de carga</li><li>Nuevo enfrentamiento</li></ul><br>¡No te pierdas todo esto por el módico precio de 5.000 euros!","etiquetas": "Esto, es, el, parche, 0.0.0"},{"titulo": "Parche 0.0.0","descripcion": "Pronto estará disponible en la BETA. Incluye correciones de errores y nuevos efectos de hechizo.","imagen": "http://orig00.deviantart.net/296e/f/2008/238/f/0/circle_of_helaing_by_namesjames.jpg",   "contenido": "El parche incluye numerosas actualizaciones. <ul><li>Corrección de errores</li><li>Nuevas animaciones</li><li>Nueva pantalla de carga</li><li>Nuevo enfrentamiento</li></ul><br>¡No te pierdas todo esto por el módico precio de 5.000 euros!","etiquetas": "Esto, es, el, parche, 0.0.0"}]');

// Metodo 1, string creada
    var list = '<div class="col-md-1"></div><div class="col-md-10">';
  var tag;
  var tags = news[0].etiquetas;
  if (tags.indexOf(",") !== -1){
   tags = tags.split(",");
   tag = "";
   for(var j = 0; j < tags.length; j++){
    tag += " #" + tags[j].trim();
   }
  } else {
   tag = "#" + tags;
  }
   list += '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="notice-middle" style="background-image: url('+
    news[0].imagen +
    ');"><a href="'+news[0].imagen+'">'+news[0].imagen+'</a><h3 class="notice-title">' +
    news[0].titulo +  
    '<span class="tag">' +
    tag +
    '</span></h3></div></div>';
     list += '</div><div class="col-md-1"></div>';
  $("#middle_notices").empty();
 $("#middle_notices").html(list);
  
// Metodo 2, creando nodos DOM
 var col_left = $("<div>", {
     'class': 'col-md-1'
 });
 var col_middle = $("<div>", {
     'class': 'col-md-10'
 });
 var col_right = $("<div>", {
     'class': 'col-md-1'
 });
  var col_md_6 = $("<div>", {
    'class': 'col-md-6'
  });
 var notice_middle = $("<div>", {
   'class': 'notice-middle',
   'style' : 'background-image: url(' + news[0].imagen + ');"'
 });
 var notice_title = $("<h3>", {
   'class': 'notice-title'
 });
 notice_title.text(news[0].titulo);
 var span_tag = $("<span>", {
   'class': 'tag'
 });
 span_tag.text(tag);
 col_middle.append(col_md_6.append(notice_middle.append(notice_title.append(span_tag))));
  $("#notices").empty();
  $("#notices").append(col_left).append(col_middle).append(col_right);
```

```css
/*
Index Header
*/
.row-header-notices {
    background-image: url(../images/background3.jpg);
    height: 650px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 50px;
}
.row-header-notices:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.row-header-notices:hover .notice-title {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffcb00;
}
.header-notice-group {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    width: 100%;
}
.header-notice-group:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.header-notice-group:hover .notice-title {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffcb00;
}
.header-notice-center {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.header-notice-title {
 font-size: 26px;
}
.header-notice-tag { 
}
.row-notices {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0px;
}
.notice-middle {
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../images/background0.jpg);
    margin:20px 0px;
}
.notice-middle:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.notice-middle:hover .notice-title{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ffcb00;
}
 .notice-middle h3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
 }
 .notice-middle h3 span {
 }
.btn-more {
 width: 115px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="middle_notices" class="row row-notices">hola</div>
<div id="notices">
hola
</div>
```

Comment: Si solo son unas comillas debería cerrarse la pregunta por **error tipográfico**

Comment: Correcto, si, perdón por no ver-lo, muchas grácias, ya me parecia muy raro a mi que me pasase eso